# Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type [IOS - SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a TO-DO list app in Xcode by using Swift, and I encounter an error writing one of the function methods on the "if let path = indexPath {" line which says "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type".

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    if let path = indexPath {            
        let currentString  = dataSource[path.section][path.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentString            
    }        
    return cell
}
```

Comment: `indexPath` is not optional so there is no need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

Use this code because I think my previous idea was not good.

You don't need conditional binding here as suggested by Leo.

Answer (score 2):

Because `indexpath` is **not optional**,you do not need to use conditional binding

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let currentString  = dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentString
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why u want use two `constant`?
fix ure code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

       cell.textLabel?.text = dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]            
   }        
   return cell
}
```